# REST web service returning always html using CodenameOne client

Tags: java, rest, tomcat, jersey, codenameone

i've created a web service via **jersey** and **tomcat** here it is:

```
@Path("/hello")
public class Hello {


  // This method is called if TEXT_PLAIN is request
  @GET
  @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
  public String sayPlainTextHello() {
        boolean flag=true;
    return "Hello Jersey";
  }

  // This method is called if XML is request
  @GET
  @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_XML)
  public String sayXMLHello() {
        boolean flag=true;
    return "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>" + "<hello> Hello Jersey" + "</hello>";
  }

  // This method is called if HTML is request
  @GET
  @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
  public String sayHtmlHello() {
    boolean flag=true;
    return "<html> " + "<title>" + "Hello Jersey" + "</title>"
        + "<body><h1>" + "Hello Jersey" + "</body></h1>" + "</html> ";
  }
```

in **Codenameone** i set the client like this:

```
public static void getRest(){

        String service="http://localhost:8080/com.vogella.jersey.first/rest/hello";

        ConnectionRequest req = new ConnectionRequest(){

              @Override
              protected void postResponse() {

              }
               @Override
              protected void readResponse(InputStream input) throws IOException {
                  // JSONParser p = new JSONParser();

                //  System.out.println(Util.readToString(input));

                  Dialog dd=new Dialog(Util.readToString(input));
                  hi.addComponent(dd);
              }

          };

          req.setUrl(service);
          req.setPost(false);
          req.setContentType(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN);


          InfiniteProgress prog = new InfiniteProgress();
          Dialog dlg = prog.showInifiniteBlocking();
          req.setDisposeOnCompletion(dlg);
          NetworkManager.getInstance().addToQueue(req);
    }
```

the default example in codenameone setted the req.setContentType("text/plain"); but changing this options in the client and in the ws the result is the same, **i always get the html** and not the xml or text...this is not so important because soon i should get json but i think i must understand this thing before going on...thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've never used CodeNameOne, but I'm pretty sure that `setContentType` sets the `Content-Type` header. In a request, that is saying that the type of data being sent by the client is that content type. But with GET there is usually no data, so the `Content-Type` is useless.

For a request, when you want to tell the server what content type you want back, you instead set the `Accept` header. When you don't set it, it usually defaults to `*/*`, which leaves Jersey to just pick one. And in your case it seems to always pick `text/html`.

Looking as the [`ConnectionRequest`](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/io/ConnectionRequest.html), I don't see any `setAccept` method, but it looks like you can use [`addRequestHeader`](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/io/ConnectionRequest.html#addRequestHeader-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-). So tre

```
req.addRequestHeader("Accept", "text/plain");
```

Answer (score 1):

**Case 1 :**
  If you want to invoke based on Accept Type headers,
Change the accept headers for text/html etc to call appropriate methods.

**`Accept Headers`**: `text/plain` to invoke `sayPlainTextHello()`

**Case 2:**
If you want to handle the call invocation based only on URI:

Note that your URI from client :

*http://localhost:8080/com.vogella.jersey.first/rest/hello*

is the root URI and not the method level URI. In case if you had methods like this:

```
@Path("/hello")
public class Hello {


  // This method is called if TEXT_PLAIN is request
  @GET
  @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
  @Path("/text")
  public String sayPlainTextHello() {
     //do something
  }

  // This method is called if XML is request
  @GET
  @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_XML)
  @Path("/xml")
  public String sayXMLHello() {
        //do something
  }

  // This method is called if HTML is request
  @GET
  @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
  @Path("/html")
  public String sayHtmlHello() {
    //do something
  }
```

As you see, you now have method level `@Path`, you can then invoke,

*http://localhost:8080/com.vogella.jersey.first/rest/hello/xml*

I just gave an example, typical implementation can be based on QueryParams taking the response type, been invoked as,

*http://localhost:8080/com.vogella.jersey.first/rest/hello?response=xml*

Comment: I would completely remove case 2. This content negotiation should _not_ be done in the url like this, unless in rare cases you are using "file" extensions like `.json`

Comment: @peeskillet I completely agree. I gave case 2 in case something forces not to handle via Accept .